# JFileChooser Issue within IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jfilechooser

I'm creating a Java program that takes in a text file with Person objects in each line of data, represented by Name, SSN, and e-mail. The purpose of the program is to compare the efficiency of a O(N*log(N)) sort against a sort as you go approach with a Sorted List abstract data structure, as well as a Hash Table. These details aren't critical to the question at hand.

The program works by prompting the user like this:

Sort and Search Lab

1. Select input and output files.
2. Gather people and generate comparison data.
3. Print list after heap sort
4. Search for a SSN
5. Close files.

When the user presses, 1. they will be prompted with a JFileChooser to take in both an input file (the data with the People) and an output file (where comparison data will be printed ect.

Now, while using an IDE called jgrasp, the program works perfectly. However, as I continue learning Java, I've wanted to switch to an IDE with more functionality, I chose to install IntelliJ. My program still runs as normal, however, upon pressing 1 to select the files, the JFileChooser dialog box does not appear at all.

Here are the main methods involved with creating the JFileChooser and retrieving the files from it:

```
/** Creates and opens a JFileChooser.
  * @returns An open JFileChooser dialog box.
  */    
public JFileChooser openJFileChooser() { 
    JButton open = new JButton();
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Input Test Data");
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text files","txt");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(open) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {}
    return chooser;
}
/** Returns an array of files chosen from the JFileChooser
  * @param A JFileChooser to pick files from.
  */                   
public File[] openFiles(JFileChooser chooser) { 
    return chooser.getSelectedFiles();        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure openJFileChooser() is even being called when run from IntelliJ? How are you reading the "1"? The format of newlines in input may be different in jGRASP and IntelliJ (/n vs /r/n).

Also, from your description it looks like you may be calling Swing methods from the main thread. If so, you need to restructure your program, as this can cause random errors. It probably isn't the cause of your problem though.